# Some one else is taking credit for the work I have done

Tags: work-environment, colleagues

I have joined a new, big company very recently (a month ago).
I work as software engineer.

I have noticed that something was not done correctly, so I created a pull request for the refactoring and showed it to my colleagues. One my colleagues suggested:

*"it's very good change, we must do it, but let's stop [for now] as we are in the middle of beta release."*

So I stopped working on it and focussed on other things. After a week I cleaned up the pull request and asked everyone to review it; on the same night I got messages from my other colleague, telling me he had copied all my changes into a new pull request with some testing changes, and asking me to close the original pull request.

I asked *"what's the point, why I should I close mine at all"*, he said he needed that for linting (there was no such urgent rush for linting), and I did close my pull request convinced that credit will go to me, and after agreeing that I will continue to work on it.

The next day my colleague did not give me a chance to finish my pull request, he finished up and wrapped up his own and convinced the whole team to deploy it.

Doesn't this sound like stealing my work?

When I asked him about this, he said: *"This is the way I am"*.

How can I explain this to my manager and what can I do to get credit for the work I have done?

Comment: What sort of credit are you looking for? What sort of credit did your coworker recieve?

Comment: If he was working on the same PR. Your contributions should be visible.

Comment: Can someone who understood the question please make an edit to clarify and reformat? Hard to read as it is now.

Comment: I can't read that, can someone sort the formatting please?

Comment: Is the coworker claiming your work as his own, or was it just merged into what they're working on and you feel you should be getting some special credit?

Comment: Did you just close your PR or did you delete it (and all relating branches?)

Comment: You can comment on the closed PR that references the new PR. *"Closing PR to move to PR#123."* And you may also comment on the new PR that states it was originally from PR#321. That way your name is on it. Also double check the new PR to see if your name is on the commit history (if he rebase/merged your stuff). To answer your question though, I don't see how this is stealing your work unless he gets a very special promotion or praise by the boss but never mentions you.